# По нажатию кнопки back и повторном запуске приложения- запускается новая копия

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

Использую фрагменты. Что необходимо сделать т.к приложение создает новую копию приложения,и получается,2 одинаковых приложения запущены

Answer (score 1):

`onBackPressed()` не сворачивает приложение, а как раз-таки вызывает метод `finish()` для вашего активити (о умолчанию). А, то что запускается по новой app - естественное явление. Нельзя не давать пользователю выйти из приложения. Вы лучше распишите для каких целей это хотите сделать. Плюс

1. `<uses-permission/>` прописываются вне application tag-a, а не внутри
2. fragments.Fragment - у вас действительно так называется активити?

Comment: т.е в классе pageadapter в котором у меня прописана логика фрагментов я переопределяю метод onBackPressed() и вызываю finish()?
в этом случае мое приложение полностью удалиться из памяти?